# sbt updates without adding io.spray artifacts

Tags: sbt, spray

I have a sbt project that was working fine but after a reload stopped loading the artifacts.  An update resolves the dependencies properly but for some reasons now doesn't include the libraries in the project as can be seen in the following show update (note no artifacts for many spray-io modules).  Any ideas how to resolve this?

```
> show update
[info] Updating {file:/Users/nnovod/LIMStales/}default-6a103f...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.2 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.akka#akka-actor_2.10;2.1.4 ...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe#config;1.0.0 ...
[info] Resolving io.spray#spray-can;1.1-M8 ...
[info] Resolving io.spray#spray-io;1.1-M8 ...
[info] Resolving io.spray#spray-util;1.1-M8 ...
[info] Resolving io.spray#spray-http;1.1-M8 ...
[info] Resolving org.parboiled#parboiled-scala_2.10;1.1.5 ...
[info] Resolving org.parboiled#parboiled-core;1.1.5 ...
[info] Resolving io.spray#spray-routing;1.1-M8 ...
[info] Resolving io.spray#spray-httpx;1.1-M8 ...
[info] Resolving org.jvnet.mimepull#mimepull;1.9.2 ...
[info] Resolving com.chuusai#shapeless_2.10;1.2.4 ...
[info] Resolving com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap#concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru;1.3.2 ...
[info] Resolving io.spray#spray-json_2.10;1.2.5 ...
[info] Resolving org.apache.poi#poi;3.9 ...
[info] Resolving commons-codec#commons-codec;1.5 ...
[info] Resolving org.apache.poi#poi-ooxml;3.9 ...
[info] Resolving org.apache.poi#poi-ooxml-schemas;3.9 ...
[info] Resolving org.apache.xmlbeans#xmlbeans;2.3.0 ...
[info] Resolving stax#stax-api;1.0.1 ...
[info] Resolving dom4j#dom4j;1.6.1 ...
[info] Resolving xml-apis#xml-apis;1.0.b2 ...
[info] Resolving io.spray#spray-testkit;1.1-M8 ...
[info] Resolving org.specs2#specs2_2.10;1.14 ...
[info] Resolving org.specs2#specs2-scalaz-core_2.10;7.0.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.specs2#specs2-scalaz-concurrent_2.10;7.0.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.specs2#scalaz-effect_2.10;7.0.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.specs2#scalaz-core_2.10;7.0.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scalatest#scalatest_2.10;1.9.1 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-actors;2.10.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.10.0 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Update report:
[info]  Resolve time: 1834 ms, Download time: 81 ms, Download size: 0 bytes
[info]  compile:
[info]      org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.2: (Artifact(scala-library,jar,jar,None,List(),None,Map()),/Users/nnovod/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.2/lib/scala-library.jar)
[info]      com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.10:2.1.4: (Artifact(akka-actor_2.10,bundle,jar,None,ArraySeq(master),None,Map()),/Users/nnovod/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.akka/akka-actor_2.10/bundles/akka-actor_2.10-2.1.4.jar)
[info]      com.typesafe:config:1.0.0: (Artifact(config,bundle,jar,None,ArraySeq(master),None,Map()),/Users/nnovod/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe/config/bundles/config-1.0.0.jar)
[info]      io.spray:spray-can:1.1-M8: 
[info]      io.spray:spray-io:1.1-M8: 
[info]      io.spray:spray-util:1.1-M8: 
[info]      io.spray:spray-http:1.1-M8: 
[info]      org.parboiled:parboiled-scala_2.10:1.1.5: (Artifact(parboiled-scala_2.10,bundle,jar,None,ArraySeq(master),None,Map()),/Users/nnovod/.ivy2/cache/org.parboiled/parboiled-scala_2.10/bundles/parboiled-scala_2.10-1.1.5.jar)
[info]      org.parboiled:parboiled-core:1.1.5: (Artifact(parboiled-core,bundle,jar,None,ArraySeq(master),None,Map()),/Users/nnovod/.ivy2/cache/org.parboiled/parboiled-core/bundles/parboiled-core-1.1.5.jar)
[info]      io.spray:spray-routing:1.1-M8: 
[info]      io.spray:spray-httpx:1.1-M8: 
[info]      org.jvnet.mimepull:mimepull:1.9.2: (Artifact(mimepull,jar,jar,None,ArraySeq(master),None,Map()),/Users/nnovod/.ivy2/cache/org.jvnet.mimepull/mimepull/jars/mimepull-1.9.2.jar)
[info]      com.chuusai:shapeless_2.10:1.2.4: (Artifact(shapeless_2.10,jar,jar,None,ArraySeq(master),None,Map()),/Users/nnovod/.ivy2/cache/com.chuusai/shapeless_2.10/jars/shapeless_2.10-1.2.4.jar)
[info]      com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:1.3.2: (Artifact(concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru,jar,jar,None,ArraySeq(master),None,Map()),/Users/nnovod/.ivy2/cache/com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru/jars/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.3.2.jar)
[info]      io.spray:spray-json_2.10:1.2.5: (Artifact(spray-json_2.10,jar,jar,None,ArraySeq(master),None,Map()),/Users/nnovod/.ivy2/cache/io.spray/spray-json_2.10/jars/spray-json_2.10-1.2.5.jar)
[info]      org.apache.poi:poi:3.9: (Artifact(poi,jar,jar,None,ArraySeq(master),None,Map()),/Users/nnovod/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.poi/poi/jars/poi-3.9.jar)
[info]      commons-codec:commons-codec:1.5: (Artifact(commons-codec,jar,jar,None,ArraySeq(master),None,Map()),/Users/nnovod/.ivy2/cache/commons-codec/commons-codec/jars/commons-codec-1.5.jar)
[info]      org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.9: (Artifact(poi-ooxml,jar,jar,None,ArraySeq(master),None,Map()),/Users/nnovod/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml/jars/poi-ooxml-3.9.jar)
[info]      org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:3.9: (Artifact(poi-ooxml-schemas,jar,jar,None,ArraySeq(master),None,Map()),/Users/nnovod/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml-schemas/jars/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9.jar)
[info]      org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:2.3.0: (Artifact(xmlbeans,jar,jar,None,ArraySeq(master),None,Map()),/Users/nnovod/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.xmlbeans/xmlbeans/jars/xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar)
[info]      stax:stax-api:1.0.1: (Artifact(stax-api,jar,jar,None,ArraySeq(master),None,Map()),/Users/nnovod/.ivy2/cache/stax/stax-api/jars/stax-api-1.0.1.jar)
[info]      dom4j:dom4j:1.6.1: (Artifact(dom4j,jar,jar,None,ArraySeq(master),None,Map()),/Users/nnovod/.ivy2/cache/dom4j/dom4j/jars/dom4j-1.6.1.jar)
[info]      xml-apis:xml-apis:1.0.b2: (Artifact(xml-apis,jar,jar,None,ArraySeq(master),None,Map()),/Users/nnovod/.ivy2/cache/xml-apis/xml-apis/jars/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted all of spray.io in the .ivy2 cache (rm -r .ivy2/cache/io.spray) and then did a new update and that fixed things.